# Account/Login not found - identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am putting identity in my already created project, but it is not locating the `Account/Login` page.

[image]

It is not localizing the page, this is the `controller`:

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public readonly Erp.Models.ErpDb _context;
    public AccountController(Erp.Models.ErpDb context, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ILogger<AccountController> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
    }
}
```

`Startup`

```
 public class Startup
{


    private IHostingEnvironment env;
    private IConfigurationRoot config;
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        this.env = env;
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        config = builder.Build();

    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ErpDb>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source =servidor; Initial Catalog = ERP; User ID = sa; Password = password;Connect Timeout=30;"));

       services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ErpDb>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
            services.AddScoped<IMailService, DebugMailService>();

        else
            services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();

        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(jsonOptions =>
        {
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            jsonOptions.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        })
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {

            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Details");

        });

        services.AddCors();
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(config.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=About}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do you also have a `Login` action within that controller? Those views are MVC views, so they don’t render themselves but need a controller action. Unless they are actually Razor pages in which case they should be within a `Pages` folder.

Comment: My controller is in the question, is something missing in it?Sorry, first time I use identity, I'm learning now.

Comment: Do those `.cshtml` files you show in that screenshot have a `@page` directive? In that case, they are Razor Pages, so you should move them all from `Views/` into the `Pages/` directory.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, I can use the account with page razor and the others not in a single mvc core project? That must be the problem.

Comment: No, you can mix Razor Pages and MVC, but I’m pretty sure that you cannot put the Razor Pages inside the `Views` folder.

Comment: I'll do the test by creating the page folder, and I'll let you know.

Comment: @poke Thanks for the tip, now it already finds the page, but it does not take the design of the main page, it is this way, since you are searching in `View`, is this the problem? `Layout = "/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using [Razor pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) for your account UI, you cannot have those `.cshtml` files inside the `Views` folder. The `Views` folder is only meant for views used by MVC but not Razor Pages.

In order to have the framework pick those up with the correct URL, you need to move them to the `Pages` directory instead.

Since you are then mixing Razor Pages and MVC in the same project (which is not a problem), you will have to adjust your layout setup in order to have both pick up the same layout file.

Basically, you need to make sure that you have a `_ViewStart.chtml` file in both the `Views` and the `Pages` folder that configure the layout to use. If you previously used MVC, then you likely already have a `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`. In that case, you need to also create a `Pages/_ViewStart.cshtml` file (you can copy it). The file should look like this:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

Then, Razor Pages will also attempt to pick up the layout at `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`, just like MVC does.

Comment: I can open the login, but I still can not do it. He does not even open the registration page.

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 8):

Just Change Code :

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

change to  :

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```